# How to get <body> in *X*HTML where document.body is missing

Tags: xml, dom, xhtml

What is the "official" way to get the `<body>` element in XHTML (=~XML) web page where there is no `document.body`? I mean something better than quering it through `querySelector` or `getElementsByTagName` which I consider ugly.

EDIT: It doesn't work for me in Firefox 3.6 when in strict XHTML mode.

Comment: It works perfectly for me (also in Fx3.6) in that mode: http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/xhtml/body.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a XML document. One should switch from `application/xml` to `application/xhtml+xml`.

Answer (score 2):

`document.body` is an official, standard property and is part of DOM2. In addition, all browsers today support it.

Comment: Right answer... but it still doesn't work for me :-) It must be my mistake.